# What is the % operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, modulo

I am trying to decipher a piece of JS code (while (obviously) my JS knowledge is null).
What is the % operator in the code below?

```
   m[p1%2][q1] = 0.0;  
   for(j=q1+1; j <= q2; j++)
      m[p1%2][j] = m[p1%2][j-1] + 1;
```

Comment: [__Remainder__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

Comment: It seems the reason for a downvote was the lack of research effort, which is one of the main reasons for downvotes. And it definitely looks like a duplicate, 4 other people appear to agree.

Comment: FYI, the `%` operator is the same (or at least very similar) in Javascript as it is in Java, C, C++, C#, Python, Perl, and doubtless other languages as well. I think C was the first to use it as the modulo/remainder operator.

Comment: asking 'What is the % operator in JavaScript?' on StackOverflow does not show the other question. StackOverflow search engine sucks.

Comment: @Tushar: Both questions talk about the same thing, `%`. If you think it's not a duplicate because the other question uses the wrong terminology we can simply update the other question ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Right, the terminology is not used in questions so, it is dupe.

Comment: Thanks to all (Tushar, Feathercrown, Avan) that posted a meaningful answer instead a random/useless comment about this question. All receive an upvote from me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%` is [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()). It gives the remainder after division.
<sup>Quoting from MDN</sup>

> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand. It always takes the sign of the dividend, not the divisor. It uses a built-in modulo function to produce the result, which is the integer remainder of dividing `var1` by `var2` — for example — *var1 modulo var2*.
>
> [There is a proposal to get an actual modulo operator in a future version of ECMAScript](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:modulo_operator), **the difference being that the modulo operator result would take the sign of the divisor, not the dividend**.

Comment: why did you mark it a comm wiki?

Comment: @DavidYue Just asking for documentation. I've just copied content from documents.

Answer (score 2):

% is modulo (or modulus?). It divides the first term by the second and returns the remainder. This can be useful for looping through a set of numbers and many other things.

Usage: x % y

Examples:

```
5 % 10; //5
10 % 5; //0
16 % 5; //1
```

Answer (score 1):

% is a Mathematical operator, it is used for Modulus.
in simple 3 % 2=1
Modulus operator returns reminder.