# Check if a date from a collection is 3, 6, or 9 months (and so on) ago

Tags: javascript, date, mongoose, momentjs

Must check if a collection of projects contains a startDate that **has passed 3, 6, and so on, months**, using `moment.js` but having problems coming up with a way to **calculate the difference in time between today and startDate**, was thinking of seeing if `(today / startDate) % 3 === 0` but I don't think that's the best way and the results are not as expected. Even using `moment.js` diff, like this  doesn't yield desired results and logs projects that clearly haven't elapsed elapsed 3, 6 etc... months. 
Obviously I'm missing something would appreciate some help thank you.

```
const today = moment()

const projects = await ProjectModel.find()
projects.forEach(project => {
    if (today.diff(moment(project.startDate), "month") % 3 == 0) {
        console.log(project)
    }
})
```

Comment: `%` is not modulo, it's [*remainder*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005330/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript). `x % 3` it doesn't tell you 3, 6, 9 months etc. it only tells you the remainder if you divide x by 3, e.g. 4%3 and 10%3 both give 1.

Comment: @RobG, you're right that `%` is used to calculate the remainder, and that's just another word for modulo. (See 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285043/how-to-calculate-a-modulo and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.)
"In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (called the modulus of the operation)."

Comment: @Cat—the [ECMAScript % operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-applying-the-mod-operator) does not conform to the mathematic definition of modulo (ECMAScript uses the sign of the dividend, modulo uses the sign of the divisor), hence it's called remainder. A link to an explanation is included in my first comment, see the accepted answer. Neither of your links is authoritative or address the ECMAScript % operator with respect to the modulo operation.

Comment: Thanks @RobG. I learned something today. They're similar, but that doesn't make them the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

% is the wrong way to go about it. You want to find the 3 month ago bracket that the date falls in, so get the difference in months and divide by 3 and floor the result. If diff < 3, you'll get 0. If 3 <= diff <6 months, you'll get 1, etc.

E.g.

```js
let projects = [
 {startDate: new Date(2017,10,1)}, // 1 Nov 2017
 {startDate: new Date(2018,10,1)}, // 1 Nov 2018
 {startDate: new Date(2019, 0,1)}, // 1 Jan 2019
 {startDate: new Date(2019, 3,1)}, // 1 Apr 2019
 {startDate: new Date(2019, 4,1)}, // 1 May 2019
 {startDate: new Date(2019, 6,1)}, // 1 Jul 2019
 {startDate: new Date(2019, 7,1)}  // 1 Aug 2019
];
let today = moment();

projects.forEach(project => {
  let diff = today.diff(moment(project.startDate), "month") / 3 | 0;
  console.log(
    moment(project.startDate).format('DD-MMM-YYYY') +
    ' was ' + (diff * 3) + ' to ' +
    (++diff * 3) + ' months ago'
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The modulo makes sense to me. If you roll your own dates, it works like this (plus or minus a leap-year-day, which is what libraries like moment.js are good at abstracting away):

```js
const projects = [
  { id: 1, startDate: 1551441600000 },
  { id: 2, startDate: 1554120000000 },
  { id: 3, startDate: 1556712000000 },
  { id: 4, startDate: 1559390400000 },
  { id: 5, startDate: 1564660800000 }
];

// Gets current year, month, and date
const now = new Date(),
      thisYear = now.getFullYear(),
      thisMonth = now.getUTCMonth(),
      thisDate = now.getUTCDate();

// Loops through projects
projects.forEach(project => {

  // Gets year, month, and date for each project
   const then = new Date(project.startDate),
     startYear = then.getFullYear(),
     startMonth = then.getUTCMonth(),
     startDate = then.getUTCDate();
  //console.log(then.toUTCString());


  // Reports on the project if it started on an earlier day of the month 3, 6, etc months ago
  const justStarted = thisYear == startYear && thisMonth == startMonth,
        isQuarterInterval = thisMonth % 3 == startMonth % 3 && thisDate >= startDate
  if(isQuarterInterval && !justStarted){
    console.log("Project #" + project.id + " started " + then);
  }
});
```